# Windows 7 Citrix Client

Tags: windows-7, citrix

I have looked, I have googled, I have gone to Citrix's website, but I cannot find the latest download for CitrixICA client! Where can I get a version (exact links please!!!) that will work with Win7!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrix has renamed many of their products.  You are looking for the XenApp client which is available [here](http://citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=1858087&productId=186&c1=sot2755&c2=ost12713).  There are two versions depending on if you use the web interface to log in or not.